# Cke editor youtube embend

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a blog and I'm using CKE editor to create articles. I've also downloaded external plugins like codesnipped or youtube. However, I'm experiencing some troubles with the last one, because it doesn't appear in the toolbar as you can see in this image:

[image]

Here's the code for the CKE EDITOR:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default':
        {'toolbar': 'Custom',

         'toolbar_Custom': [
             ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
             ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
             ['Image', 'youtube','Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
             ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
             ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'], ['CodeSnippet',] ,
         ],
         'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codesnippet','youtube']),
        }
}
```

And the models.py in case you need it:

```
lass Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Comment: try uppercase Youtube in ```['Image', 'youtube','Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],```

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks